# Communication between windows phone and .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, windows-phone

I made a windows phone application using .NET and a website using asp.net .

Now I want the window phone application to call a function that is in a .aspx page.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better take a look at web services and web api, and of course , you can call a function in your aspx page, you can supply parameters by using query strings.

Check out this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call a to a function that is in aspx page. You can expose some methods in a web service, and then consume it in your aspx, your windows phone or wherever.

Comment: As a matter of fact , you can.